# Compile angular directive dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

If I add angular material directive md-button like this :

```
angular.element( document.body ).append( '<md-button> Material' )
```

It will not recognize that it's angular directive.
The question is - how to recompile scope/element

Comment: Although I understand what you are asking, I don't think appending like this is a good idea (angular should append everything you need for you, so It does everything it needs to do on the DOM before you see the directive on your screen).

Comment: It is actually what i need. After DOM is rendered i need to add dynamically directive to DOM and render/recompile it. Is it possible?

Comment: I will give exactly the same advice as @MVCDS . Yes this is possible but i'd really not post a clear solution that beginner to angular may read (that may lead them to some really bad practices). I'd rather know why you think you need this ? There may be a cleaner way to add this md-button.

Comment: When the button was clicked i must dynamically add the element to the DOM which is directive.

Comment: Tell us more about this "when the button was clicked" It sound like a usecase for ng-repeat or ng-show/hide instead of angular.element().append(). What are you trying to do ?

Comment: It can be any directive element from angular material, and i don't know which one will be added and it is not possible to recognize how many it will be.

Comment: I actually think that what you need is a router ... or just a good use of angular build-in directives. Can you provide the global context ? here is a plunker with some dynamic html content using angular ... does it cover some of your needs ? http://plnkr.co/edit/IteGzrEmPHKNs3glJY5T?p=preview

Comment: Thank for the answer but it is not applicable for my case. In solution you use ng-repeat and in my case it don't will be there, because I don't know place where the element will be added.

Comment: If you dont give anymore information i will not have the keys to help you out.

Comment: my case is: 
1. I don't have any directive before DOM loaded
2. I need add any directive from angular materials in any place of DOM dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you should be doing this, but the right way is to use the `$compile` function:

```
angular.element(document.body).append($compile('<md-button> Material')($scope))
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FH2fk5XQ9ZnfvD9IdsTP?p=preview).

Comment: This worked for me but Im curious why everyone seems to consider this bad practice?  My use case is Im creating 'panels' to display information about an object when the user clicks on it, and then destroying them when the user hits the 'close' icon on them.  Im thinking it is better to do it this way rather than constantly updating an ng-repeat as in Okazari's example - but perhaps this is because I dont understand Angular well enough?